# HTML codes in strongly typed HTML helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, I am having a hard time getting this to work. I am trying to add some typographic HTML codes to some labels I have strongly typed to my model.

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) %>
```

I am using data annotations to customize the `DisplayName` of the property.

```
[DisplayName("Your friend&rsquo;s name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

However the actual code is being displayed for the label:

```
Your friend&rsquo;s name
```

I have also tried just using the old write method:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) %>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to do this. I simple used the actual rendered codes and it displayed fine.

```
[DisplayName("Your friend’s name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

LabelFor will always encode the string to Html. You may wish to create an override for this helper, to output the string not encoded. Such as Html.HtmlLabelFor()

Source code for MVC is available too if you need to look at the innards of the original helper. 
http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet

If you are using MVC3 and Razor then all strings are encoded to HTML when rendered on the page. Then you should to look into the HtmlString class if you return this to a helper class then it will render as HTML.

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/12/27/HtmlRawRazorViewEngine.aspx